# Jquery, blur event inside click event

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery, and I'm not able to understand on how to use a 'blur' event inside a 'click' event.

My project has

- A toolbox: where there is a button to add elements to canvas
- A canvas: all the elements added appear here
- A editor Window: Where I can see/edit the elements properties

here is a sketch of my project:[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s56ku8L9/2/)

Each element I add to canvas will have two representations: An object, and a visual one that is a div.

The point is: When I add elements to canvas I can click them, and I can edit their atributes in Editor window. The elements have a text atribute and It's name.

But If I have for example: 2 elements on canvas and try to change the text atribute of one of them (in the editor window), It changes all the elements text attribute. My problematic function is the following:

```
$(function(){   
canvas.delegate('.myElement','click', function(){
    var obj = this;
    myTextArea.val(this.text);
    myTextArea.on('blur',function(){
        obj.text = myTextArea.val();
    });
});
```

});

Can someone tell me where I'm failling? Thanks for the help guys

Comment: when you're adding the element on the canvas, try adding an eventlistener as well.

Comment: You should (almost) never have event handlers inside other event handlers, they just keep compounding. Everytime someone clicks the element, a new `blur` event handler is added, so it runs the code twice, then thrice, then four times etc. on each blur event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the blur event each time an element is clicked.

You could declare a variable to keep track of the element that was clicked:

```
var currentElement = null;
```

And then bind the blur handler:

```
myTextArea.on('blur',function(){
    if (currentElement) {
        $(currentElement).text(myTextArea.val());
    }
});

canvas.delegate('.myElement','click', function(){
    currentElement = this;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises from previously attached blur handlers, which remain attached and need to be detached before a new one is attached. To detach, use `.off()`.

```
$(function() {
    canvas.on('click', '.myElement', function() {
        var obj = this;
        myTextArea.val(this.text).off('blur').on('blur', function() {
            obj.text = myTextArea.val();
        });
    });
});
```

That should fix the problem but you might like to consider a more efficient approach, in which a single blur handler stays permanently attached to the textarea.

```
$(function() {
    myTextArea.on('blur', function() {
        var element = $(this).data('element');
        if(element) {
            element.text = this.val();
        }
    });

    canvas.on('click', '.myElement', function() {
        myTextArea.val(this.text).data('element', this);
    });
});
```

Here, `myTextArea.data('element')` is used to store a reference to the most recent `.myElement` clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

blur function is fired whenever the element loses focus , just declare the event outside click function :

```
  myTextArea.on('blur',function(){
          obj.text = myTextArea.val();
   })
```

make sure obj is defined in.function scope.